# Swift Optionals: When should you be expecting them

Tags: swift, option-type

So I am teaching myself Swift and I get optionals when I am declaring them, so for example:

```
var thisString:String?
```

I would have to either force unwrap thisString, or use

`if let anotherString = thisString {`

or use

```
guard if let another string = thisString else { return }
```

or nil coalesce it

```
let anotherString = thisString ?? "Something else"
```

But where I am getting hung up is there are times I create something that I don't think it an optional but the compiler does.

For example, why is the URL an optional here?

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2")
var myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
```

I didn't declare it as an optional and it clearly has a value. So why does the compiler see this as an optional? If I didn't force unwrap it I would get this error:

```
Value of optional type 'URL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Is there some standard that I am missing? I've gone over both the docs and Swift Programming Book from Big Nerd and I still don't seem to get this part.

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: But you did (implicitly) declare it as an optional. Look at the definition for `URL(string:)`.

Comment: You've got the correct answer below (not every string resolves to a valid URL), but I'd like to point out that this is a safety feature - you're supposed to check whether you actually have a valid URL, and overriding it by force unwrapping (!) defies the purpose of optionals. Get out of that habit now.

Comment: @green_knight Even better advice: don't use `URL(string:)`. It's almost never correct to use it. The URL should be formed using URLComponents.

Comment: Ha, that's where I ended up, built a closure to build the and return the URLComponents.

Comment: @matt Not something I need very often (thanks for the reminder, it'll come in handy!), this was more about the general principle because I see 'optionals are an inconvenience circumvented by exclamation marks' too often.

Answer (score 4):

> But where I am getting hung up is there are times I create something that I don't think it an optional but the compiler does.

But what you think is not what matters. What matters is what the API call you are making actually returns. You find that out by reading the docs.

> So why does the compiler see this as an optional

Well, let's read the docs. You are calling `URL(string:)`. That is the same as URL's `init(string:)`. Look at the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779737-init

The declaration is

```
init?(string: String)
```

See the question mark? That means, "This call returns an Optional." So you should expect an Optional here.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't determine if the url that you define in the string is valid or not.

Suppose instead of:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2")
```

You miss typed the myURL definition as:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https:/itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2")
```

The string contains a malformed URL, so the program would crash the moment you went to define myURL.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So, in the case of instantiating from a string URL will always be an optional?

Comment: Exactly right.  I struggled w/ options for a long time. But they do make sense.  So you must declare myURL as an optional, or unwrap it safely in the ways you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let myURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2")
```

Here you are creating an url from string.That string might not be a valid string.**All the strings are not valid url.** So you are getting an optional because if that string can be turned in to a valid url then that url will be returned else nil will be returned. See the [Apple documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url)The initializer what you are using is a failable initializer itself.

```
  init?(string: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Keshav is correct, to get a better idea, hold the option button and click on the 'string' part of the init function for the `URL` class.  You will see in the swift reference the init declaration is `init?(string: String)`.  This means that a optional is returned.  Any function can return a optional, you can have `func returnMyString(_ myString: String) -> String {}` or `func returnMyString(_ myString: String) -> String? {}`.   Both of those functions are pretty much the same, except the second one returns a optional.

Answer (score 0):

`URL` has optional initializers. For example you can have

```
class A {

    init?() {
        return nil //You will get Optional<A>.none
    }

}

A() === Optional<A>.none //true
```

which kind of implies that initialization failed. Such initializers wrap returned object into Optional. In Swift `nil == Optional<Any>.none` so you can speak of them interchangeably.

For example if you will attempt to construct a `URL` with something that is not an actual url, it will return nil.

```
let notAURL = URL(string: "{") //notAURL will be nil
```

On a side note: I believe optional initializers are a very poor design choice since they don't communicate anything about what went wrong inside the `init`. If init is fallible, it should `throw`. I don't understand why Swift designers allow optional initializers and I see why it births a lot of confusion.